# React Native(0.72.3) Android build fails at App Center

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

I added AppCenter to the initial React Native Project and I got the error while building the Android app.

I followed these steps:

1. Create a new project for Android and React Native at AppCenter.
2. Created a new project using `npx react-native init AppCenterTest`.
3. Followed the steps from App Center.

- `yarn add appcenter appcenter-analytics appcenter-crashes --save-exact`
- Create a new file with the filename appcenter-config.json in android/app/src/main/assets/ with my secret key
- Push to github

4. Set build configuration
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
5. Save and run build

During the Gradle task in the build process, I get the following error:

```
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
 - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
 - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Gradle 8.0.1
Gradle 8.0.1

> Configure project :gradle-plugin
Resolved org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.22 in detachedConfiguration1 
Resolved org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.22 in :classpath 
Project react-native-gradle-plugin at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...

> Configure project :
Project AppCenterTest at : is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AppCenterTest'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
        Required by:
            project :
      > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
        Required by:
            project :
         > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
             - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
             - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
                 - Other compatible attribute:
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
             - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
##[error]Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:509:12)
##[section]Finishing: Gradle Task
```

Here's the result from `npx react-native info`

```
System:
  OS: macOS 13.4.1
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Memory: 63.02 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.16.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.5.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.07.10.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /Users/dev/.asdf/shims/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3/14E222b
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 19.0.2
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.7.5
    path: /Users/dev/.asdf/shims/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.3
    wanted: 0.72.3
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

It's the raw project and I didn't add any libraries.
`./gradlew assembleRelease` works fine on local and also I was able to build an APK using Android Studio.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCNOr.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JDK11 is installed by default. Just set environment variable JAVA_HOME to $(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this worked even in 2023, but with latest version.